# Two vectors inside a function

Tags: python, function

I am new on Python.

I want to create a function with two vectors inside. I tried like this

```python
def twovectors((velocity1,length1),(velocity2,length2)):
```

but I have a message error like

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax.

Please,  need help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot put tuple in the function definition as a parameter. Check [Multiple Function Arguments](https://www.learnpython.org/en/Multiple_Function_Arguments) or [8.6. Function definitions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) in the Python language reference.

Try something like this this:

```
def twovectors(vector1, vector2):
    velocity1, length1 = vector1
    velocity2, length2 = vector2
    # Other code...
```

I used [tuple unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) to expand provided tuple arguments.

Answer (score -1):

You write functions in python in this way :

```
def twovectors(velocity1, velocity2):
    # You can get the length of those vectors after you get inside the function
    len1, len2 = len(velocity1), len(velocity2)
    // Your code here

    return whateveryouwantto
```